# What do i let the particular solution equal in this equation $ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-y = e^{2t} + e^{-t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

howdo i solve this differential equation?
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-y = e^{2t} + e^{-t}$$

so far i have that by letting 
$y=e^{mt}$ and plugging it in gives the complimentary solution:

$$y_c(t)=C_1e^t + C_2e^{-t}$$ for arbitrary constants C_1 and C_2.

now i don't know what to let the particular solution to equal? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry made an edit to the variables they're meant to be t not x

Comment: try a $Ae^{2t}+B t e^{-t}$

Answer (score 0):

..............
$$y_p=Ae^{2t}+Bte^{-t}$$

then 
$$A=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$B=\frac{-1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can solve first for $\exp(2t)$, then for $\exp(-t)$. For the first case, letting $y = A \exp(2t)$ and finding a suitable $A$ should be enough. For the second case, write $y(t) = B(t) \exp(-t)$ to lead you to the equation $B''(t) = 1$, which should be easy enough to solve.